# Basic Authentication with Spring boot for Rest services

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to implementing the basic authentication with spring boot for Rest Service endpoints.Below is my sample code.I don't have Database to store the username and passwords and using a application.properties to store the passwords.My rest services will be used by fron end system and it is not ****recommended to share the plain passwords to frond systems**** ,Can anyone suggest how to generate the passwords which is secure .Can we generate the random number ?
Can we use BCryptPasswordEncoder for random number password ?

```
  @Configuration
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() 
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
    http.csrf().disable();
   }

  @Bean
   public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(password);
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername(username).password(encodedPassword).roles("USER").build());
    return manager;
  }

 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }
 }
```

Comment: why are you storing the passwords in `application.properties`?

Comment: I don't have Database to store the passwords